# In Futurama, how many beings has Leela slept with?

Tags: futurama

How many different beings has Leela slept with in *Futurama*?

So far I count only 3 (Fry, Zapp and Bender), am I missing some?

> "You were like a machine!"
>
> Leela in Ep. 7ACV16 T.: The Terrestrial

Comment: Should we count Kif? -- they did make babies, after all.

Comment: @R.M. - An excellent point. We can't judge 'what is sex?' by our own narrow human standards.

Comment: I don't think that's any of our business...

Comment: @Harper - And yet here we are....

Answer (score 22):

We have specific confirmation that Leela had sexual relations with;

- Her ex-boyfriend **Sean** (the jazz-noodling imbecile)
- Captain **Zapp Brannigann** (The "Velour Fog")
- Delivery Boy 1st Class **Philip J. Fry**
- **Lars Fillmore** ("Lars Lars and his fabulous jars")
- Her former fiancée **Alkazaar**
- **Cubert J. Farnsworth** (in an alternate timeline)
- Lieutenant **Kif Kroker**
- **Yivo** (along with every other being in our universe)

She may have also have had sex with

- ("Perfectly ordinary") **Dr. Adlai Atkins** - *Multiple dates*.
- ("Mayor's Aide") **Chaz** - *Multiples dates*.
- **Doug** (with the "vile lizard tongue") - *One date.*
- ("The crusty old dean") **Dean Vernon** - *One date*.

---

For the record, she appears to have "made out with" (but not had sex with)

- **Bender**
- **William Shatner**
- **Amy Wong**

Comment: Two of those are the same person.

Comment: @OrangeDog - You'd think she woulda noticed *that*, at least.